# Is that correct that input and output pins are not supposed to have current through them?

Tags: voltage-level, current

Are input and output pins not supposed to have current through them and only either apply voltage or "measure" it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An output pin (on an AVR 8-bit board like an Arduino Uno) can pass up to 40mA (*absolute maximum*). It is recommended not to exceed 25mA.  This is called *sinking current* when the output pin is set to LOW, and *sourcing current* when it is set to HIGH.

An input pin is what is known as *high impedance*. I.e., it looks, to the circuit connected to the pin, like an incredibly high value resistor connected between the input and ground. Because of that only very tiny currents will ever flow through it (unless you do something silly like plug it direct into the mains).

Answer (score 3):

First, you can not apply a voltage to or with an I/O pin connected to a circuit, and have no current flow as a result. There is a limit to the current a given pin on a given device can pass without damage and that is specified in the device's datasheet. How much current a given pin and circuit will pass or try to pass depends on the external circuit and the circuit internal to the device. Majenko's answer (except possibly for the specific limits, depending on the device) is correct.

You haven't specified what device. Is this a generic question or is it specific to the AVR micro-controllers used in most Arduino boards? If the latter, the limits in @Majenko's answer are also correct.

Answer (score 2):

What everyone else said.

It's difficult to measure voltage without taking at least a tiny trickle of current, and that's what input pins do.

Anything that is driven needs current to drive it (power = current * voltage). However, an arduino pin - as someone mentioned - should only ever be used to supply about 25mA. Drawing a heavier current than that can fry the chip.

V=IR, so, the resistance on an output pin should be no less than 200 ohms, hence the 330 ohm current-limiting resistor you put on an LED. Power is IV, so the maximum power you can safely get get is 125mW (oh, you can get more - but you may fry your chip). This translates directly into the maximum safe brightness of a LED, the strength*speed of a motor, the loudness of a buzzer powered by an output pin.

Another big thing when trying to drive coils (motors, solenoids, relays) is that when you switch off the power to a coil, it generates a spike of voltage going the other way. This spike also can fry the chip. This is why relay shields are a thing - they contain electronics to deal with this back-emf. If you want to drive a motor and don't want to buy a shield, look into darlington array chips. I used one to run a stepper - worked perfectly.

So.

- Inputs in theory need almost no current - but they do need that tiny trickle.
- Outputs must have current to do any work. The amount you can get off the board without frying it is limited.